# Done callback from WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.essentials

in my XF application I have the possibility to open a web page.

For do this I use the Xamarin.Essential: **await Browser.OpenAsync(url, opts);**.

I need to have a callback when the user tap on **Done** button (on iOS) or the **back** button (on Andorid).

How can I do this?

There is another way other than use Xamarin.Essential?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I need to execute some C# code when the user tap on the "done button" in iOS or the back button on Android when the WebView is open.

I'm not trying to execute some JavaScript code, or execute C# code from Javascript.

[image]

[Android video](https://ufile.io/gegxphms).

[Sample here.](https://ufile.io/yzvytab5)

Comment: If  want to get such an event in the browser, I don't think this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah if you don't want to use Essentials for opening pages, you could use

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("www.example.com"));
```

And if you want it to be in a async fucntion

```
await Device.OpenUri(new Uri("www.example.com"));
```

And if you are looking into adding callback functionality from the webview, you would need to create a HybridWebView and custom renderers for iOS & Android, [as shown here](http://krystianczaplicki.com/mobile/communication-between-xamarin-forms-application-and-webview/).

Comment: Hi, I have tested this solution but this isn't what I tried to do.
I have edited the question.

Comment: @Hikari can you please share iOS & Android screenshots in the description of these Done and Back buttons that you are talking about? Are these buttons in the webview, or are they on the Page. If they are on the page and not in the webview, try to do this for Android-> protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        _webView.GoBack();
        return true;
    }

Comment: The buttons are on WebView :(

Comment: The back button on Android is an easier fix, try this in your page:- protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed() { _webView.GoBack(); return true; }

Comment: For iOS, there's a more complicated way, but try this https://wolfprogrammer.com/2016/07/07/custom-app-header-in-forms/

Comment: I have added a sample project :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195582/discussion-between-saamer-and-hikari).

Answer (score 0):

We solve this by setting a flag when we send the user out to the browser, and then checking for the flag when we return in `OnAppearing()`.

```csharp
public partial class PurchasePage : ContentPage {

  bool isPurchasing = false;

  protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
    base.OnAppearing();
    if(isPurchasing) {
      isPurchasing = false;
      // Check if purchase completed successfully, etc...
    }
  }

  public BeginPurchase(){
    isPurchasing = true;
    await Browser.OpenAsync("https://example.com/purchase")
  }
}
```